# Access struct members inside a class private members?

Tags: c++, struct, private-members

For Example:

**graph.h**

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class graph
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        string name;
        int currentValue;
        struct node *next;
    };
    node* head;
public:
    graph();
    ~graph();

    graph(string* newName, int* givenValue);
}

#endif
```

**graph.cpp**

```
#include "graph.h"

graph::graph() {}

graph::~graph() {}

graph::graph(string* newName, int* givenValue)
{
    //This is what I want to achieve
    this->node->name = newName;                    //Compile error
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "graph.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0; //Note I have not yet created a graph in main
}
```

How can I access the **struct node** members for the function above?

**This is the error:**

```
graph.cpp: In constructor ‘graph::graph(std::string*, double*)’:
graph.cpp:24:8: error: invalid use of ‘struct graph::node’
this->node->label = newName;
```

Comment: What you want to do is : `this->head->label = newName;` ; `node` is a type, not a member data. Anyway, I suggest you don't use a pointer, i.e.: define `node head;` instead of `node* head;`, then use `this->head.label = newName;`

Comment: nitpicking sometimes helps: You dont access the member of a struct/class, but the member of an instance of a struct/class

Comment: what kind of weird graph it is, man ? Are you sure you did not mean tree ?

Comment: `this->head->name = *newName; `

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with your private struct. The constructor should be able to access all private members.

The problem as that you confused the struct name `node` and the variable name `head`:

> this->node->name = newName; // incorrect

Instead you should write:

```
 this->head->name = *newName;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the class variable you should call

```
this->head->name = *newName;
```

though you can omit `this->` so the following is fine

```
head->name = *newName;
```

Couple of other notes:

- `string* newName` is a pointer so you need to access its value with the dereference operator "*" (i.e. `head->name = *newName;` instead of `head->name = newName;`
- `node* head` is a pointer and currently you are trying to access an uninitialized pointer. You probably need something like `head = new node();` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to private access. First, add `;` to end your class declaration:

```
class graph
{
    // ...
};
```

Then, you typed `this->node->name` while `node`is a type. Change this line for `this->head->name`. Note that the pointer `head` is uninitialized here.

And then, `newName` is of type `string*` while `this->head->name` is of type `string`. Depending on how you want to use your class, you may consider modifying your code like this:

```
graph::graph(const string& newName, int givenValue):
    head(new node)
{
    //This is what I want to achieve
    this->head->name = newName;
}
```

Or like this:

```
graph::graph(string* newName, int* givenValue):
    head(new node)
{
    //This is what I want to achieve
    this->head->name = *newName;
}
```

Also, read about [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).